# Karate Validate multiple possible values using schema match

Tags: karate

Below is the `schema.json`, value of `city.area.status` can be either "`ACTIVE`" or "`INACTIVE`",

```
Schema.json
{
   "name": "#string",
   "city":{
      "area": {
         "type": "#string",
         "status": "ACTIVE"     
      }
   }
}
```

I am validating the entire schema using

```
* match each Response.hits.hits[*]._source == objectCatSchema
```

Except `city.area.status` field, Without using `#string`, is there any way I can validate that value is either `ACTIVE` or `INACTIVE`

Validation:

```
* def Response = call read ('`testResponse.json`')
* def expectedSchema = call read ('`citySchema.json`')
* match each `Response.hits.hits[*]._source == objectCatSchema`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be other ways, but here you go:

```
* def statuses = ['ACTIVE', 'INACTIVE']
* def schema = { status: '#? statuses.contains(_)' }
* def response = { status: 'ACTIVE' }
* match response == schema
```